# Trying to launch InternetExplorerDriver for WebDriver, get InvalidOperandException

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-9, webdriver

I've been successfully using WebDriver with the firefox browser, but this is my first attempt at using the Internet Explorer browser.

I'm simply doing this:

```
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"C:\bin");
```

When I execute, it brings up on the console:

```
StartedInternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
2.31.0.0
Listening on port 51572
```

But then throws the following exception:

```
Invalid OperandException 
Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. IELaunchURL() 
returned 80070005 for URL 
'http://localhost:51572/' (NoSuchDriver)

System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2146233079
Message=Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. IELaunchURL() returned 80070005 for URL 'http://localhost:51572/' (NoSuchDriver)
Source=WebDriver
StackTrace:
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
    at OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerDriver..ctor(InternetExplorerDriverService service, InternetExplorerOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
    at OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerDriver..ctor(InternetExplorerDriverService service, InternetExplorerOptions options)
    at OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerDriver..ctor(String internetExplorerDriverServerDirectory, InternetExplorerOptions options)
    at OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerDriver..ctor(String internetExplorerDriverServerDirectory)
```

Comment: What version of Selenium and IE and is anything listening on that port? Can you reproduce this on a *different* computer?

Comment: Selenium 2.31.2, IE 9.0.8112.16421.  This problem only seems to happen on my machine :(  A co-worker of mine can run it successfully on his.

Comment: Have you tried the 32-bit version of the IE Driver? I assume IE opens fine when run manually?

Comment: Yes, I've tried both 64 bit and 32 bit driver and neither work for me.  IE does open fine when I open it manually.  Also, I've brought up the driver manually, then brought up IE manually and pointed it to the port that the driver is on, and that works successfully too.  The problem seems to be the inability to launch IE from within the visual studio/webdriver environment.